# Return same Type as Generic Class

Tags: c#, generics, casting, extension-methods

Wasn't really sure how to phrase the title.

What I am trying to achieve is a deep clone system for `IEnumerable<T>`s where `T:ICloneable`.

I have written the, as-yet untested, method below which I believe should work:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> DeepClone<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) where T:ICloneable
    {
        return source.Select(s => (T) s.Clone());
    }
```

However, this returns an `IEnumerable<T>` (as one would expect) and I am curious as to whether or not it is possible (without causing an unacceptable overhead) to return the base type of the `IEnumerable<T>` instead.

For example, running `List<int>.DeepClone()` would return a new, cloned `List<int>` and running `int[].DeepClone()` would return a new, cloned `int[]`.

I know that I can quite easily just cast my `IEnumerable`s after calling this method, but I'm hoping to be able to avoid this.

There is also the option of creating a whole load of overloads, one for each `IEnumerable` but if it's possible to I'd like to avoid this.

Comment: Why you need that? Let the caller make this if desired. Your job is done by returning the cloned objects, the caller should (be able to) decide what he wants to do with it.

Comment: Well I'm writing this method into a Utility Library that I maintain for my own use. I need the method because on another project that I'm working on, there are objects which require deep cloning of various different types of IEnumerable fields.

Comment: Even if it was possible(f.e. by using reflection or simply `source is List<T>`), you would still return `IEnumerable<T>`, so the caller must cast it anyway. So the best way (if you really need this) is to provide different methods for every collecrtion-type.

Comment: There's no generic way to know how any particular `IEnumerable<T>` has been/needs to be *populated*.

Comment: This would require higher-kinded polymorphism which C# does not support.

Comment: You can do something like `TCollection DeepClone<TCollection, TItem>(this TCollection source) where TCollection : ICollection<TItem> where TItem : ICloneable` but it has its own problems (like inability to automatically infer generic type arguments.

Comment: Okay, I'll go with the overloaded approach I think. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to build explicit methods for the concrete types you want to support (List, arrays etc).

An example:

```
public static List<T> DeepClone<T>(this List<T> source) where T : ICloneable
{
    return source.Select(s => (T)s.Clone()).ToList();
}
```

Alternatively, use an approach like:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DeepClone<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) where T : ICloneable
{
    var result = source.Select(s => (T)s.Clone());

    if (source is List<T>)
    {
        return result.ToList();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: So I was correct in thinking that there might be no other way to do this?

Comment: That is my understanding, yes.

Comment: I dont like the `source is List<T>` approach because it's a _hidden_ feauture and the caller needs to cast the returned sequence to a `List<T>` before he can use it like one. If he uses `...DeepClone(...).ToList()` to "cast" it there is no need to call `ToList` yourself anyway.

Comment: I agree @TimSchmelter . The former is definitely preferred.

Comment: @JamesHughes: Nothing prevents you from making a **second** method, `DeepCloneToList<T>()`, which returns a `List<T>` (instead of `IEnumerable<T>`) and whose body does nothing more than `return DeepClonce<T>().ToList();`. THen you don't need to automatically call `.ToList()`, but you will specifically have to call on that second method.

Comment: Makes sense, was just hoping there was a better, more terse way, thanks guys.